# lack of precision in calculation sin cos & tan (java)

Tags: java

When I run this piece of code

```
System.out.println( Math.cos(8.8485279795) ); // should be : 0.988098452127
System.out.println( Math.sin(23.437101628) ); // should be :0.397742095267
System.out.println( Math.tan(52.2166666666667) ); // should be : 1.289966871548
System.out.println( Math.cos(23.437101628) ); // should be :0.917497261932
System.out.println( Math.sin(8.8485279795) ); //should be : 0.153822784089
```

the output is this;

```
-0.8385118249144639
-0.9922171619691422
-2.500855651260892
-0.12451949041776937
0.5448833998926885
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: These functions take angles in radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a lack of precision, it's because you are passing degrees to functions that require radians. Use [`Math.toRadians(double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians-double-) to fix. Like,

```
System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(8.8485279795)));
System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(23.437101628)));
System.out.println(Math.tan(Math.toRadians(52.2166666666667)));
System.out.println(Math.cos(Math.toRadians(23.437101628)));
System.out.println(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(8.8485279795)));
```

And I get (as you expected)

```
0.9880984521266581
0.39774209526711635
1.2899668715484742
0.9174972619318948
0.1538227840890365
```

Comment: It worked!, thx  ;)